# android create common libraries

Tags: android, libraries

how do we create common libraries in android that can be used across applications? I want to write some classes which are accessible by all applications. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, Go to Project Properties --> Android . Select 'Is Library' checkbox. That is it.

To use this in other projects, Select Project Properties (of the other project --> Android--> Add (underneath the 'Is Library' checkbox) and select the library)

more instructions here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: not exactly sure on netbeans. But here is the method to do it on 'non-eclipse' environment. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject